# Remaning filename.txt for the first line of the txt

Tags: python, unix, terminal

I am writing a script with Python in which multiples files are going to be generated with the same name. I need in each itineration, change the name of the txt for the first line of this txt. I have followed some links in StackOverflow but I got problems.

Here my code:

```
for myfile in allfiles:
    if myfile.endswith(".fna"):
        print(com1)
        print(com2)
        #We move the document that interests us.
        print("cp /Users/monkiky/Desktop/control/output.align/gtdbtk.bac120.user_msa.fasta  /Users/monkiky/Desktop/control/ultimate_output/concatenates")
        # Filename must be rename, let's rename with the name of the bacteria (first line in the document).
        #print('mv /Users/monkiky/Desktop/control/ultimate_output/concatenates/gtdbtk.bac120.user_msa.fasta "$(head -1 /Users/monkiky/Desktop/control/ultimate_output/concatenates)"')
        #We move the document that interests us.
```

If I just write this in the terminal

```
mv /Users/monkiky/Desktop/control/ultimate_output/concatenates/gtdbtk.bac120.user_msa.fasta "(head -1 /Users/Desktop/control/ultimate_output/concatenates)"
```

I got this output

```
head: Error reading /Users/monkiky/Desktop/control/ultimate_output/concatenates
mv: rename /Users/Desktop/control/ultimate_output/concatenates/prueba.txt to : No such file or directory
```

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

1) in this command:

```
mv /Users/monkiky/Desktop/control/ultimate_output/concatenates/gtdbtk.bac120.user_msa.fasta "$(head -1 /Users/Desktop/control/ultimate_output/concatenates)"
```

the file passed as the argument to `head` should be… yes, **the file**, not the directory in which it resides. So:

```
mv /Users/monkiky/Desktop/control/ultimate_output/concatenates/gtdbtk.bac120.user_msa.fasta "$(head -1 /Users/Desktop/control/ultimate_output/concatenates/gtdbtk.bac120.user_msa.fasta)"
```

2) calling a shell command from Python to do this simple operation is a bad idea. The right way to do it in Python does not involve shell:

```
import os
myfile = '/Users/monkiky/Desktop/control/output.align/gtdbtk.bac120.user_msa.fasta'
with open(myfile, 'r') as f:
    firstline = f.readline().strip()
os.rename(myfile, firstline)
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help.

I got the same output. head: /Users/Desktop/control/ultimate_output/concatenates/gtdbtk.bac120.user_msa.fasta: No such file or directory
mv: rename /Users/monkiky/Desktop/control/ultimate_output/concatenates/gtdbtk.bac120.user_msa.fasta to : No such file or directory

But the directory exist because if I write less /Users/Desktop/control/ultimate_output/concatenates/gtdbtk.bac120.user_msa.fasta I can open the file

Comment: That's simply not possible. If `less /Users/monkiky/Desktop/control/ultimate_output/concatenates/gtdbtk.bac120.user_msa.fasta ` works, `head /Users/monkiky/Desktop/control/ultimate_output/concatenates/gtdbtk.bac120.user_msa.fasta ` must work too. Probably you're making a typo.